# displaying a URL on a surface

Tags: texturing, video

I have a URL that may be an embedded video or a series of web animations(sort of like a slideshow) on a webpage and I am wondering if it's possible to display that within blender (e.g. on a panel or face of a cube)? Basically would it be possible to display a website within blender?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to take an image/video of the website and apply that to an object as a texture, but it won't be interactive. Will such an approach work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in a direct and interactive way.

Firstly, Blender can connect to a URL and retrieve the raw html in text form. However, Blender cannot render this html into a visual format and then use it as an image texture. There may be online web services that render an html document into an image (like a screenshot), but Blender would then have to download that image before importing and applying it as a texture.

Secondly, images or videos that are sourced through a URL cannot be directly set as the texture source for a material. The files would have to be downloaded via python and then loaded via a local filepath value. This is possible but would require some steps with scripting, and would not be immediately interactive.

The same goes for a video file or a sequence of images. They would all have to be downloaded from the remote URL location before being able to be loaded into blender as textures.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like [CEF Python](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython), project that should allow you to embed the Chrome browser in other applications.

There is currently still an [open issue](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/121) that I think may need you to do some extra work to get it going, but with this you should be able to embed a browser to show web pages inside Blender in panels.

You'll have to go through the documentation to find out how to do it, but with the off-screen web-page rendering capability it should be possible to get this working.